# Bind to Window view model property when its not the data context

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding, mvvm, relativesource

The current data context is SomeViewModel  but I need to bind to a property on the view model of the main window.  Im guessing I need to specify Source or RelativeSource in the binding but not quite sure how to manage that.  The MainWindowViewModel is the data context of the main window (and is also a public member).  Any guidance most welcome!

Comment: I think you're breaking the MVVM design pattern here. You should have that property on your "SomeViewModel" and source it from the same place in both view models.  Alternatively, pass the value into the view as a parameter when you navigate.

Comment: @Robaticus I thought about piping the property to SomeViewModel - but Im not using a dependancy property - so I need to manage RaisePropertyChanged on SomeViewModel when the property changes on WindowViewModel and thats not obvious (its easy on the WindowViewModel).

Comment: I got you.  I also understand that the real world often interferes with the perfect implementation of any design pattern.  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like

```
{Binding Path=DataContext.YourMainWindowViewModelPropertyName, 
         RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}
```

It should work if your main window is instance of Window type, and your current "object" is sub-UserControl.